# vb.net: How do i split a delimited file out into separate files depending on the flag i set in the code

Tags: vb.net, split

I've got a pipe delimited file that has multiple different flat lines of data.

I want to split out depending on the first field in the data so that i end up with two data files (one with the data i have selected and the other with the remaining data)

e.g

**FLAG|random data|random data|random data|random data|random data|random data|
FLAG1|random data|random data|random data|random data|random data|random data|
FLAG2|random data|random data|random data|random data|random data|random data|
FLAG1|random data|random data|random data|random data|random data|random data|**

So all the data with FLAG1 would be in one file and then the rest (FLAG2) would be saved off in a separate file.

So far i have this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim c As Integer

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim Tr As IO.TextReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("C:\Users\gmck\Desktop\TIG DATA\test_1")
        For c As Integer = 0 To 1500

        Next

        If c = 0 Then
            Dim MyFileLine As String = Split(Tr.ReadToEnd(), vbCrLf)(c) & vbCrLf
            Tr.Close()

            Dim TW As System.IO.TextWriter
            'Create a Text file and load it into the TextWriter 
            TW = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\Users\gmck\Desktop\TIG DATA\test_NEW")
            TW.WriteLine(MyFileLine)
            'Flush the text to the file 
            TW.Flush()
            'Close the File 
            TW.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

which pulls out the first record and puts it into a new file.  I can't think how to get it to pull out all the records for a specific flag.

cheers for any help.

Gaz

Comment: No newlines? How big is the input file?

Comment: input file could be anything up to 15,000 lines (around 4mb in size)

Comment: And have you had a go at figuring this out yourself?  If so, please post examples of what you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: I've not, i think this is a stretch too far for me :(  All i've managed so far is the open file dialogue to grab the file :(

Comment: I managed to find some code on here that helped a little but didn't do exactly what i want so i've uploaded it to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: first of all it reads the file splitting on `vbcrlf` to get all the rows within the file.

Then it iterates through the collection of rows checking whether they start with "FLAG1" or "FLAG2". Depending on this condition it writes in the first or second file.

```
Private Sub Read()
    Dim Tr As IO.TextReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("f:\input.txt")

    Dim rows As String() = Tr.ReadToEnd().Split(vbCrLf)
    Tr.Close()

    Dim TW1 As System.IO.TextWriter
    TW1 = System.IO.File.CreateText("f:\output_1.txt")

    Dim TW2 As System.IO.TextWriter
    TW2 = System.IO.File.CreateText("f:\output_2.txt")

    For Each row As String In rows
        row = row.Trim
        If row.StartsWith("FLAG1") Then
            TW1.WriteLine(row)
        End If

        If row.StartsWith("FLAG2") Then
            TW2.WriteLine(row)
        End If
    Next

    TW1.Flush()
    TW1.Close()

    TW2.Flush()
    TW2.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: One comment: using statements. they are your friend

Comment: This is absolutely perfect thank you :) It's now outputting the one flag and i've got it outputting the remainder of the data into the second file :)

Comment: How hard would it be to amend the code so if i search for a specific HEX position it would replace it with the number i enter in the "FLAG1" or "FLAG2" position?  Would it change from textreader to bytereader or something like that?